# ThreadStart delegate does not execute until Console.Readline() is provided

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have some problem with ThreadStart delegate. After I provide a function and start the thread nothing is actually happening. I need to add `Console.Readline()` to write messages to a file. Why it behaves like that?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThreadStart
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
            {
               int messageSeq = 0;

               while (messageSeq < 5)
               {
                   File.AppendAllText(@"c:\Test\write.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                   messageSeq++;
                   Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
               }
            }));
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have experience in multi-threaded applications so i might be missing something simple

Comment: Once `Main` finishes, the entire app shuts down. `Console.ReadLine` delays `Main` from finishing, giving your extra thread time to do its work.

Comment: if you set IsBackground to false, this will keep the process running until the thread completes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Thread.IsBackground Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> A thread is either a background thread or a foreground thread. Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that background threads do not prevent a process from terminating.

You're telling the thread not to force the application to stay running, and then you're letting the application close by returning from the `Main` method.

`Console.ReadLine();` will stop the application returning from `Main` and will give the thread time to do it's work.

[Thread.Start Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9fyxz7d(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Note that the call to Start does not block the calling thread.

The `Start` method of the `Thread` doesn't block the calling thread. That means it returns ~right away and the calling thread continues to execute.

[Console.ReadLine Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)

> If the standard input device is the keyboard, the ReadLine method blocks until the user presses the Enter key.

`Console.ReadLine()` does block the calling thread until the user hits enter/return in the console (causing a new line).

Comment: No worries, good luck with your adventures in multi-threading!